# LED lights on the keyboard - assembly

Tags: assembly, keyboard, dosbox

How can I turn on/off the lights in the keyboard using assembly?
I already tried

```
 Mov Al, oedh
Out 60h, Al
Mov Al, 111b
Out 60h, Al
```

And it didn't work
I'm using DosBox to run the asm files

Comment: It's possible DOSBox doesn't emulate the lights on keyboard because it wasn't something games used.

Comment: Ok, thank you. How can I run 8086 asm files without dosbox?

Comment: You can try installing MS-DOS in a VM, like VirtualBox.